# Problem with LCD 128x240 pinout

Tags: lcd, glcd

Recently I bought a 128x240 LCD with ts6963c driver chip. The part number is TS240128D-1. I am familiar with KS0108 driver but the problem is different pinouts.
I found a good manual in a book for ts6963c and expected a 19 pins module but the module contains 22 pins.Here is the data sheet:[TS240128D-1](http://www.tme.vn/upload/pdf/TS240128D.pdf)

I dont know what the pins "pin4: VO" , "pin19: VOUT" doing there. Are they connected with a potentiometer to each other and ground as is in ks0108? 
On the other hand, in page 2 of that data sheet, pin 22 is named "DSPON" (Display ON?) but in top of the next page it is named "NC" (Not Connected?). What is this pin doing?
It would be a great help if anyone can answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, pin 19 must be connected to a potmeter, other side to ground, wiper to pin 4. No value is specified, I always take 10k.

I think page 2 is copied from a display where pin 22 had a function, and the table lateron which lists it as NC is correct. I sell a display that looks a lot like yours, but mine has only 21 connections. You might check the traces to see whether your 22 is connected to something.

Comment: Thanks . Many years ago I had a module with ts6963c but with only 19 pins.The pin number 4 was named CON ( Contrast Control) instead of "VO" and should be connected to a source with -10 volts. If pin4 in this module is connected to VOUT (pin 19) and ground, I guess this module has an internal circuit for making a -10 volts on VOUT. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, check the table on p22.